# Get objects and SelectedIndex from ListViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a list view that I bind to an OservableCollection of class ticket. It creates the list fine, but when the item click event is fired the SelectedIndex is always -1. How can I get the index of the clicked item? Each item also has some objects inside of it. How do I get address ability to the objects inside the listviewitem. I can get the text from ticket object, but accessing the checkbox, or whatever object I might need to put in there is confusing me. This is a windows phone 8.1 project.

Xaml code

```
<Page
x:Class="BindingTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BindingTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="LV" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="LV_ItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="LVIGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              MinWidth="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding iflag}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               FontSize="36" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding kflag}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="36"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding qty}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                               FontSize="36"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding itemStr}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               FontSize="24"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding priceStr}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               FontSize="24"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

C# code behind

```
namespace BindingTest
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ticket> ticketCol;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        ticketCol = new ObservableCollection<ticket>()
        {
            new ticket(){iflag="I",kflag="k",qty="1",itemStr="Test Item",priceStr="9.99"},
            new ticket(){iflag="I",kflag="k",qty="2",itemStr="Test Item",priceStr="9.99"},
            new ticket(){iflag="I",kflag="k",qty="3",itemStr="Test Item",priceStr="9.99"},
            new ticket(){iflag="I",kflag="k",qty="4",itemStr="Test Item",priceStr="9.99"}
        };
        LV.ItemsSource = ticketCol;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

        // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
        // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
        // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
        // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
        // this event is handled for you.
    }

    public void createTable()
    {

    }

    public class ticket
    {
        public string iflag { get; set; }
        public string kflag { get; set; }
        public string qty { get; set; }
        public string itemStr { get; set; }
        public string priceStr { get; set; }

    }

    private void LV_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string test = ((ticket)e.ClickedItem).itemStr;

        int index = LV.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `SelectedIndex` hasn't changed at the moment `ItemClick` event fired. As alternative, you can try to get clicked-item index from the `ObservableCollection` using [`IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132410%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, for example :

```
private void LV_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedItem = (ticket)e.ClickedItem;
    string test = clickedItem.itemStr;
    var collection = (ObservableCollection<ticket>)LV.ItemsSource;
    int index = collection.IndexOf(clickedItem);
}
```

For the 2nd question, I don't think there is a clean way to get UI controls from `DataTemplate`. XAML works best using data-binding so we can manipulate the underlying model/viewmodel instead of manipulating UI directly from C#.

If you really need to do that, *maybe* this can help (it is for WPF though) : [WPF - Retrieve Child DataTemplate Control From Custom ListBoxItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822842/wpf-retrieve-child-datatemplate-contr)

Comment: Thank you that worked fine for finding the index, and the link is exactly what I needed for getting the objects inside the DataTemplate.